# Dissapearing "+" in php string where "-" shows up fine

Tags: php

How can I fix or avoid a missing + symbol in my string.
I used the same code with the - and it works fine.
I have tried using  $num1."+".$num2 with no luck, very strange.
[Photo of broblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6wJ3.png)

```
if(stripos ($text, 'add') !== false){
    $trimtext = substr($text,3);
    $num1 = strstr($trimtext, '+', true);
    $trimnum2 = strstr($trimtext, '+', false);
    $num2 = str_replace("+","",$trimnum2); 
    $result = $num1 + $num2;    
    file_get_contents("$website/sendmessage?&parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=$chatid&text=<code>$num1 + $num2 = $result</code>");       
}

if(stripos ($text, 'sub') !== false){
    $trimtext = substr($text,3);
    $num1 = strstr($trimtext, '-', true);
    $trimnum2 = strstr($trimtext, '-', false);
    $num2 = str_replace("-","",$trimnum2); 
    $result = $num1 - $num2;    
    file_get_contents("$website/sendmessage?&parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=$chatid&text=<code>$num1 - $num2 = $result</code>");   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that "+" is a *space* in URL encoding.  You need to replace "+" with "%2B" in the query string.

To correct Nehal's answer, you want

```
file_get_contents("$website/sendmessage?&parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=$chatid&text=".urlencode("<code>$num1 + $num2 = $result</code>"));
```

You don't want to URL encode the contents of the $website variable or the other query parameters, but rather to prepend them to the URL encoded string.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Smooth solution.

Comment: Pro tip:  If you replace `"$website/sendmessage?&parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=$chatid&text="` with `$website.'/sendmessage?&parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=$chatid&text='` it will be slightly faster because PHP doesn't have to parse the string looking for variables:  Single-quoted strings are *not* parsed, double-quoted strings *are*.

Comment: good tip thanks. Although in example given the $chatid is variable.

Comment: `$website.'/sendmessage?&parse_mode=HTML&chat_id='.$chatid.'&text=xxx'`

Answer (score 0):

The following characters have special meaning in the path component of your URL (the path component is everything before the '?'):

```
  ";" | "/" | "?"
```

In addition to those, the following characters have special meaning in the query part of your URL (everything after '?'). Therefore, if they are after the '?' you need to escape them:

```
 ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
```

For a more in-depth explanation, see the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

According to PHP docs:

> Note: If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces,
>   you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

So, all you gotta do is:

```
file_get_contents(urlencode("$website/sendmessage?&parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=$chatid&text=<code>$num1 + $num2 = $result</code>"));
```